# Can someone explain to me about Kinematics relation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

This is my first time asking in stackexchange and I'm just an ordinary Indonesian highschooler so I'm sorry if I do anything wrong.

I can't describe the question with words so I attached a picture of it

What is the relation between the angular acceleration and the acceleration of mass m1 and the acceleration of mass m2 and the "falling" acceleration of the pulley itself. I have different answer with my teacher. My answer is number 1 while my teacher's is number 2. How to properly explain to the wrong one? Because neither me or my teacher can give satisfactory explanation.
Thank you[image: It's the question with both my and my teacher's answer.]

Answer (score 3):

HINT:  consider the case where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are the same.  Ask yourself the following questions:

- What should the linear acceleration of the pulley be in this case?
- Will the pulley rotate in this case?
- Are these answers inconsistent with either of the possible solutions?  (Hint<sub>2</sub>:  they are in fact inconsistent with one of them, and so that one must be wrong.)

---

Since you seem to be starting out in physics, here's a general piece of advice:  One of the best habits to cultivate when you're learning physics is to consider special cases.  If you know what's "supposed to happen" when the parameters of your problem take on some specific values, and your equation doesn't agree with that, then it's a good sign that something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that I can't understand the diagrams in the central part of your picture but I can still explain why your perspective is wrong.

Since you are solving a little higher level problems, I'm assuming that you are well aware of tension in a string.

Let's look at the problem from pulleys from of reference:

As m1 moves a little towards right(forget for a while about m2) you would see that the string(on left side) would have no tension for a while.

At the next instant according to you the rope should kind of move towards m2's side and slow the acceleration of m2.Thats a bit absurd!

Instead, this would happen and after reading I think you will understand why you answer is wrong.

As m1 moves a little towards right and the string(on left side)has no tension for a while,the pulley having mass has a chance(tendency) to move downward because gravity acts on it and there is no pulling force upwards and it is important to note that as m2 is moving  towards left, it would also kind of loosen the string on right( no tension) and this would make pulley go more downwards rather than what you are expecting.

It's kind of intuitive and if you have any problems in understanding please be free to ask in comments

And welcome to 'stack exchange'.

Comment: Your argument seems to be based on dynamics (i.e. the forces of tension & gravity), but this is a kinematics problem.  It should be answerable without any mention of forces.

Comment: I thought that it would be the best and easiest way...well I'm sorry for being off-kinematics... So should I delete my answer (I'm new to answering, so it would be great if you guide)

Comment: No worries!  You'll get the hang of it soon.  It's up to you whether you delete this answer or not.  You're welcome to leave it up, but it may attract downvotes if people think it's incorrect or off-topic.  (And I do think it's incorrect, BTW — take a look at the hint I give above.)